# Message not displayed after max duration reached in mediarecorder xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mediarecorder, screen-recording

Toast message is not showing though recording is getting stopped at 2mins(MaxDuration is 2mins)
It is not hitting the below method only

```
private void MediaRecorder_Info(object sender, MediaRecorder.InfoEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.What == MediaRecorderInfo.MaxDurationReached)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(context,"Maximum duration reached",duration).Show();
     }
}
```

Comment: Is the `Info` event being called at call? Have you set a breakpoint on the `if` condition? Have you set a listener via the native `SetOnInfoListener` method (that will disable the C# event that Xamarin creates)?

Comment: I tried with keeping a breakpoint on if, it isn't working. I didn't find any solution for xamarin to use the SetOnInfoListener, if possible can you provide some example

Comment: Try creating a custom class to inherit from the `MediaRecorder.IOnInfoListener` interface to override the OnInfo method to achieve the function. Check the code: `MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.SetOnInfoListener(new CustomInfoListener(this));
...

public class CustomInfoListener : MediaRecorder.IOnInfoListener
{
    public void OnInfo(MediaRecorder mr, [GeneratedEnum] MediaRecorderInfo what, int extra)
    {
        if (what == MediaRecorderInfo.MaxDurationReached)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}`.